# How do I select and manipulate a rig?

Tags: armature

Downloaded this IK rigged model: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/72307

Opened it in Blender, but I'm not able to figure out how to interact with the rig. When I try to select one rig/joint, Blender selects the whole rig/all the joints. How can I select one, and only one rig/joint(for instance, the foot)?

I've used Blender for other stuff for a couple of months. I've also animated in other software, so I'm not new to the theory. I just don't understand Blenders interface for using rigs.

Comment: Are you in [pose mode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Posing)?

Comment: Not sure, how do I get into pose mode? I can't see any shortcuts or buttons in the link you provided.

Comment: For other users: Ctrl + tab shifts to pose mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be in [*Pose Mode*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Posing).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> with the rig selected, or select *pose mode* in *3D view > Header*:

[image]